# Loading a factory from a non angularAMD module after bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

In this plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/IpewSU) I have created a factory 'LoggerFactory' that is registered in module 'webapp'. The factory is used in controller 'logCtrl'. This controller get's loaded after bootstrap in case the route is '/log'. There is a module 'LoggerModule' and the LoggerFactory should belong to this module not 'webapp'.

When I load the factory before bootstrapping (e. g. add the dependency in 'webapp') I can create the factory in that module. Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fn6rxg

But loading the factory before using it is no solution for a large application...

What I'm missing? Does every factory need to be created in there own module and when: how to inject this module to another already bootstraped module?

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using this solution to register elements to external modules in angularAMD app:

```
// bind submodules to register their functions here
app.run(function() {
    var bindRegister = function(module, type) {
        return function() {
            module.register[type].apply(null, arguments);
            return module['_'+type].apply(null, arguments);
        };
    };

    var t, type, types = ['controller','factory','directive','filter','service','constant','value','animation'];
    var m, module, modules = ['AccountModule', 'NoticeModule'];
    for (m in modules) {
        module = angular.module(modules[m]);
        module.register = app.register;
        for (t in types) {
            type = types[t];
            if (typeof(module[type]) == 'function') {
                module['_'+type] = module[type];
                delete module[type];
                module[type] = bindRegister(module, type);
            }
        }
    }
});
```